# set option with formgroup in dropdowns option in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have setup this formgroup

```
 holidayform: FormGroup;

 this.holidayform = this.fb.group({
      title: ['', [Validators.required]],
      entryDate: ['',],
    })

 this.holidayform.patchValue({
      title: data.title,
      entryDate: data.entryDate,
 })
```

this is my dropdown in my component :

```
<form [formGroup]="holidayform">
 <select class="form-control"> <option value="Globals" [selected]="holidayform.title=='Globals'">Global</option>
 <option value="Locals" [selected]="holidayform.title=='Locals'">Local</option>
 </select>
```

`[selected]="holidayform.title=='Globals'"` this is not working i want to select it based on the value i patched in the formgroup.

Any solution Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selection is defined by the bound FormControl. Tell Angular, that the select is bound to the `title` control within `holidayform` by using `formControlName`. Now, if `data.title` is *Globals* when you patch it, Global option gets selected.

```
<form [formGroup]="holidayform">
  <select class="form-control" formControlName="title">
    <option value="Globals">Global</option>
    <option value="Locals">Local</option>
  </select>
```